# Extending the contact card in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mobile

Can I register an app to appear in contact cards? So as well as call mobile, text, send email, etc, can I add an additional option?

I'm assuming not, because otherwise WhatsApp would do it, but I'm just checking.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible.
Your application can be seen in some hubs of the phone but not in the contact card.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. Such a shame, the whole point is apps should be able to cut across hubs and be contextual. Anyway. Thanks :)